# plotting high dimensional data in java

Tags: java, plot

I have thousands of data points and each data point has 50 dimensions. I would like to see the sparseness of data using java. Is there any java package/methods to plot such high dimensional data.

Comment: Regardless of language, how do you anticipate that you would want to visualise 50-dimensional data?

Comment: How many dimensions are you able to perceive at once?

Comment: i would like to see in 2-D, yes but what i am asking is , is there any tools that can do dimension reduction and plot it in 2D so that i can see the relation among different data points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to look for is [multidimensional scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling). It basically reduces the dimensionality of the data space, trying to maintain the distances.

So you take a MDS package, reduce your data to 2D (or 3D) and plot them using 2D/3d graphics library (swing, jogl).

It might work or not, depending on the number of the data points and the space they're in. For 50 dimensions you might be out of luck, but it really depends.

A quick google for java implementation got me [this](http://www.inf.uni-konstanz.de/algo/software/mdsj/)

There's a package in R too, so you can use that.

Comment: I want to plot those points and see the how they are related.Which data points are related and which data points are not similar. If not similar, how far they are.

Comment: that's exactly what mds does. It takes your points and reduces the dimensionality, so you can plot them with any graphic library of your choosing.

Comment: i mean having points in 2D space you can plot them even using swing